# Angular routing in production - htaccess

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I have an angular 7 application where I use routing like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomePageComponent},
  {path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyPageComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];'
```

In localhost everything works fine. If I type in the browser's address bar:

- localhost:4000/ -> I go to the homepage
- localhost:4000/privacy -> I go to the privacy page

The problem is when I deploy it in production (Apache). I already edited my .htaccess as suggested by the Angular docs like this.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

But in this case (of course) If I type in the browser:

- localhost:4000/ -> I go to the homepage
- localhost:4000/privacy -> I go to the homepage again

The routing basically works only if I go to the homepage and I click a link with routerLink="/privacy". If the user types the complete URL directly into the address bar of the browser, I'm not able to visit the page.

What can I do to allow Angular to serve all the pages defined?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this `const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomePageComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyPageComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sourav, unfortunately it didn't work. Any other suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure but you might [**check this**](https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566), might be helpful!

Comment: Thank you, I finally found a useful article on internet it wasn't easy at all, because the title of the article is not obvious at all...http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/apache-htaccess-for-html5-push-state-manipulations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found this article: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/apache-htaccess-for-html5-push-state-manipulations

The title of the article is not obvious at all that is able to solve my problem, but anyway I post it here for the other people who may struggle with the same problem:

Basically I solved editing my .htaccess, this is the entire piece.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html
```

Comment: DUDE THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! NOTHING F... worked previously. And i have searched at least 10 stackoverflow pages, followed angular docs.. nothing worked